# How to create an Android app connected with Google Cloud SQL in the backend instead of the App Engine datastore?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to create an Android app that would retrieve a list of locations from a cloud based database that are in a given radius around the user's location. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1) is an article by Google describing how to implement this in websites. Since my project is Android based and I do not have any past experience in web hosting, I decided to create an App-Engine-connected Android application instead of working with a MySQL database that was used in the Google's tutorial.

However, it seems that the App Engine Datastore does not allow inequality comparisons on more than one field in a query. In my case, I would need to query both latitude and longitude to filter the nearby results.

So I think that Google Cloud SQL would probably be a better choice for me. Can I connect to the Google Cloud SQL from my App-Engine-connected Android project through its auto-generated client endpoint library?

I would greatly appreciate the advice of this community in this matter. Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint simply calls your own appengine code, from there you can do anything like querying the sql.
Note that there are other ways to do this in the datastore, see geolocation library implementations there are some out there for the datastore. Otherwise its easier to code for sql but you will have to pay the price it ha$

Comment: Thanks for helping out, Zig! How would other SQL providers like Amazon be relative to the datastore in terms of ease of implementation in Android and the costs incurred?

Comment: Thats a different q but s.o wont like it because is not about code :)